# Best way to print template inside data-ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Inside my loop variable(array of objects) there are 6 conditions on the basis of that I have to build the template.
Each type inside array of an object has the different layout, with few similar structure. To fulfill same I have to add the good amount of ng-if condition.

What should be the best way to print a template using data-ng-repeat?

I used this way......

```
    <div class="{{obj.type}}" data-ng-repeat="obj in arrayOfObj track by obj.id">
          <div data-ng-if="obj.type==='1'">Some logic nd cta</div>
          <div data-ng-if="obj.type==='2'">Some logic nd cta</div>
        <div data-ng-if="obj.type==='3'">Some logic nd cta</div>
        <div data-ng-if="obj.type==='4'||obj.type==='5'||obj.type==='6'">
Type 4 Type5 Type 6 <div data-ng-if==='4'>This</div>
    <div data-ng-if==='5'>This nd cta</div>
    <div data-ng-if==='6'>This</div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to address this situation.  one alternative method would be to create templates named to match each of the possible `obj.type` values and do something like `ng-include="'{{obj.type}}.html'"`

Comment: ... or `ngSwitch`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by segregating your ng-if logic inside a separate scope function.

```
<div class="{{obj.type}}" data-ng-repeat="obj in arrayOfObj track by obj.id" ng-include="getAppropiateTemplate(obj)">

</div>
```

Then in controller

```
$scope.getAppropiateTemplate = function(obj) {        
    switch (obj.type) {
        case "1":
            return 'partials/sometemplate.html';
        case "2":
            return 'partials/othertemplate.html';
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you the idea.